# IE automatically sets object width to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, vlc

I am using JQuery to dynamically add a vlc plugin to a page but IE automatically sets object width and height to 0.
this is the object tag I am appending to the page

```
<object width="285" height="185"
id="A9AC8F7084A4743A8198A6E1EF89BA1"
classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab"
style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 285px; height: 185px;" events="True">
<param name="Src" value="rtsp://10.1.34.236:654/01000000-0001-BABE-0007-000F7C140DF5/live">
<param name="controls" value="false">
<param name="autostart" value="true">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="false">
<embed name="A9AC8F7084A4743A8198A6E1EF89BA1" width="285"
height="185" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
target="rtsp://10.1.34.236:654/01000000-0001-BABE-0007-000F7C140DF5/live" autoplay="false">
</object>
```

when I inspect the element this is the markup I find

```
<object width="0" height="0"
id="A9AC8F7084A4743A8198A6E1EF89BA1"
classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab"
style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px;" events="True">
<param name="Src" value="rtsp://10.1.34.236:654/01000000-0001-BABE-0007-000F7C140DF5/live">
<param name="controls" value="false">
<param name="autostart" value="true">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="false">
<embed name="A9AC8F7084A4743A8198A6E1EF89BA1" width="0"
height="0" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
target="rtsp://10.1.34.236:654/01000000-0001-BABE-0007-000F7C140DF5/live" autoplay="false">
</object>
```

Comment: Try `width: 285px!important; height: 185px!important;`

Comment: I tried this but IE automatically sets it back to 0